# Is it possible to make an un-expanded Accordion pane click-through?

Tags: java, javafx

The center area is a ZoomPane containing various polygon groups that can be dragged around and zoomed into using the mouse-wheel. I like having the accordions on either side that reveal the canvas underneath when not expanded, but they prevent clicking through them to the pane underneath:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd6UU.png

Is there a good way to keep the accordions accessible on top of the canvas when not expanded, but still allow clicks through to zoom/pan the pane underneath?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TitledPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html) (or a set of TitledPane's in a VBox with a computed preferred size) instead of an [Accordion](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html).

I could not explain to you why the TitledPane's work in this case but the Accordion does not.